# Django delete superclass update or delete on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two django models, one subclassing another,

```
class A(models.Model) : 
    .
    .
class B(A) : 
    .
    .
```

the problem is when I'm deleting class A I'm getting

> update or delete on table "a" violates foreign key constraint "b_a_ptr_id_53f8796d_fk_a" on table "b"

Shouldn't the delete automaticly take out the row on table B pointing to the deleted element? Can anyone guide me through this please.

Comment: "constaint_a_b" indicates you either didn't copy-paste the error message (but typed it manually here, with typo), or you've added a constraint yourself. If the latter, you should show a bit more of your models.

Comment: Please add the fields on your models.

Comment: Also are you "deleting class A" or "deleting an _instance_ of class A"?

Comment: @9769953 I updated the constraint name

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın they're trivial fields ( no foreign keys ) but I'll put them later

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm just deleting an instance

Comment: So basically, the first example in [this documentation section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Are there any `Meta` classes?

Comment: @9769953 basically yes, deleting the superclass instance would get me this error, there's no meta classes

Comment: Do you delete this via the Django ORM or via a SQL query / raw query? Or do you perhaps have a `OneToOneField` with a `parent_link=True` in `B`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat there are no onetoonefield, and the delete happens using ORM, but even when deleting from the database directly with sql query it gives me constraint error knowing that I use postgres

Comment: @nassim please add how you are deleting the instance to the question.

Comment: Is this the initial model setup, or have you changed the models and applied some migrations? It could be the database isn't correct anymore (I've had to do a complete reset to get rid of a constraint problem).